# How to connect Electron.js with Java code for desktop applications?

Tags: java, electron, desktop-application

I am building a simple notepad application. I want to build the front end with electron.js and for file handling or database I want to use Java as back-end language. How should I connect Electron with Java back-end. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Electron combines the Chromium rendering engine and the Nodejs runtime. Electron itself is backend. There are 2 main parts at Electron. Renderer and Main process. Main process will be built on top of Nodejs.
So to connect your Java code, you should build the java code to executable bin file. And we can communicate between Electron like this

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const javaExternalService = spawn(cliPath, [args]);

javaExternalService.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`Daemon stdout: ${data}`);
    resolve(data.toString());
    // Here is where the output goes
});
javaExternalService.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`Daemon stderr: ${data}`);
    resolve(data.toString());
    // Here is where the error output goes
});
javaExternalService.on('close', code => {
    console.log(`Daemon closing code: ${code}`);
    // Here you can get the exit code of the script
});
```

But this will low your Electron performance. How about connect and manage the DB at Electron Main process.

Comment: what's clipath? is like "java myjar.jar"?